# Timed Tasks in iOS

Tags: ios

This question is an extension / alternative to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856572/push-notification-without-apns) (which didn't receive any responses). Instead of trying to achieve push notifications, I'm okay with polling the server at regular intervals. But this polling needs to continue beyond the 10 mins which are allocated to background tasks.

Are there anything like timed tasks in iOS (think cron-jobs / daemons)?

One more twisted way I could think of was, if I integrate twitter framework in my app and have my server send direct message, will it wake up my app? I know this sounds really lame as in how will the iOS know which app to deliver the notification to, if notifications are recd...

Thanks and anticipating some replies :)

Comment: "Are there anything like timed tasks in iOS (think cron-jobs / daemons)?" - No.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you against using push notifications for whatever you are trying to do? [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) seems to allow sending up 1000000 push messages per month for free on their basic plan.

Anyway, I can't think of any other way.

Comment: Hello EarlyRiser, Sorry I had quoted the wrong thread in the question. I'm developing this for a client and users will be using it in a setup where they will have access to company's internal servers over WiFi but will not have access to internet (security and infrastructure limitations). Hence APNS will not work for me. Apologies for the confusion. Enterprise Distribution is also not an option because, it will also need to be delivered to that client's customers. And legal clauses of Enterprise account don't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is very likely a "no" but I did do some pretty some hackish stuff back then, so this may or may not work for you (no guarantee):

When an app receives a notification, it triggers the app delegate's applicationDidLoad() method and the notification object is stored in the "launchOptions" parameter.

In this method, you MAY be able to execute an action to poll your server.

So what I was thinking was, setup a local notification to fire at the date you desire. Local notification are like push notification, they can execute even if your app is terminated (killed from the background process)

Then in your app delegate's didFinishLaunchingOptions(), you can check to see if it's the matching notification, if yes, then execute your desire server polling logic, else ignore.

Note: if your server polling logic is in another view controller, do realise these view controllers may not actually be initiated until you actually click on the tab to view them. Now because your app is terminated and not running, you obviously can't tap on a tab.

The second hack is to call the getter "view" method of your view controller containing the server polling logic e.g:

```
// force iOS to initialize the view controller
[MyCustomVC view];
```

As you can see, very hackish and not recommended.

Comment: Hello Zhang, very interesting hack indeed. Before I invest time in trying this out, can you tell me if this is an app-store safe method? It is essential for my app to be hosted in app-store. Thanks

Comment: I have released an app that uses these hacks. One of the features of my first app I wrote (now you know why it's so hackish) included region monitoring feature. We needed a way to present deals to user when the apps is relaunched from terminated state, after they have entered a region. That's where I discovered these two hacks. Seems to work in my case and the app is on the app store :)

Comment: Hello Zhang, I tried you hack yesterday but couldn't get it to work. No executable code is called until app comes to foreground again. Can you please illustrate you point with a small code snippet? You can assume my server-polling code is in AppDelegate so I don't need to invoke any view controllers.

Comment: Sorry ameyazing, I did say no guarantees. In my case to see the deals, the user had to relaunch the app. The only thing that allows the app to perform an action in terminated state is region monitoring callback methods. I was able to write a text file to the app even when app terminated but you're not dealing with region crossing.

Comment: Hey Zhang, I can probably insert my network call where you wrote to file. Both are executable code after all. If you can help me with your code snippet, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Region Monitoring is only triggered when you cross a region, it doesn't get triggered based on time. If the user does not enter/exit a region, the code will never fire, I don't see how that will help your code.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Point taken and thanks for you interest :)